# Oracle SQL Syntax to Find Distinct Data over 24 Hour Time Period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that tracks the login history of users to an application.  Currently, this table has has several logins per day for most users since their browser session expires.  I have a need to write a query to give me the the distinct user names for a each user who has logged in over a 24 hour time period for the life of the application (over a year). I need to get rid of the multiple daily logins. How would you combine a distinct within a 24 hour time range using the date_created timestamp field below?

table name: LOGIN_HISTORY

```
Name         Null     Type               
------------ -------- ------------------ 
ID           NOT NULL NUMBER(19)         
DATE_CREATED          TIMESTAMP(6)       
USER_NAME             VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select distinct users per day, select days and users and make them distinct with the DISTINCT keyword:

```
select distinct trunc(date_created), user_name
from login_history
order by trunc(date_created);
```

Comment: date_created has data like 2014-04-08 01:39:11.684000 for many users.  when I run your suggestion it filters out more than it should for 2014-04-08.

Comment: I don't understand. It filters out duplicates. If on 2014-04-08 you had 1000 different users, it will show you those 1000 users for 2014-04-08, no matter if they logged in once or a million time that day. Isn't this exactly what you asked for?

Comment: This query returns 16 records select distinct user_name
from login_history
where trunc(date_created) = to_date('08-APR-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') but when I run select distinct trunc(date_created), user_name
from login_history it only returns one row for 08-APR-2014.  There are multiple user logins per day.  I just want to know the distinct users who logged in for each day for a given date range or the entire range in the table.  Some other days return more than one records but it never matches the correct number of records if i verify manually.

Comment: So you say there are different users on 2014-04-08, but the query returns only one of them? This cannot be. Maybe they are simply not in order, so you don't spot the others? I am editing my answer accordingly to give it a sort order. To check your data try this: `select date_created, trunc(date_created), user_name from login_history order by date_created;` and check the 2014-04-08.

Answer (score 0):

> "the distinct user names for a each user who has logged in over a 24
>   hour time period"

Why not use DISTINCT?

> "how would I run that for a years time dynamically?"

By filtering on the date in the WHERE clause:

```
select distinct trunc(date_created) as login_date
         , user_name
from login_history
where date_created >= to_date('&&start_date', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
and  date_created < add_months(to_date('&&start_date', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),12)
```

Comment: that query is fine, but how would I run that for a years time dynamically?